# Mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$query_user2 = mysql_query("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM $var WHERE id = (rand() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM $var))");
$estrai2 = mysql_fetch_array($query_user2);
```

Problem: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Why? :/

Comment: Please at least glance at the hundreds of questions about that error message here and elsewhere. Look at the "Related" sidebar for a start.

Comment: Probably because you have a syntax error in your query. Look at mysql_error() after you've run the query to find out what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

`TOP 1` is a sql server ( not MySQL ) command to select the first row, remove that and add `LIMIT 1` to the end of the query.

*you might want to alter your question. The problem is your query, not the "supplied argument is not a valid mysql result"*